# Hamburger menu doesn't work on iphone and page content doesn't load properly

Tags: wordpress, webfonts, hamburger-menu

I've built a website using wp ocean theme, it works fine on a bigger screen and android phones, but having issues with iphone. The hamburger menu doesn't seem to work, also main page content doesn't load.
here is the site quadcountyhomehealth.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the console there are two errors shown:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' in (index):6

There seems to be CSS injected (?) in a `<script>` tag.

and

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> at autoptimize_afe04899ec612bf032dfee6dde977f40.js:2

This could be caused because jQuery is also minified and it's messed up the order of loading. (jQuery not being present in time) There are ways to exclude certain files from minifying.

Does the menu work when you disable Autoptimize and WP-Super-Cache? I wouldn't suggest using two different caching plugins on top of each other as they may cause conflicts.

This is not a direct answer, because the question is vague, but I would suggest looking for errors in the developer tools before trying anything different.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I deactivated wp-super-cache, and js optimization, and it worked.

Comment: @IlonaVardanyan No problem, glad it helped. If you could mark my answer as accepted that would be greatly appreciated. Take care!